# How to force StyledText to break line in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to force the `StyledText` to breake the line but the effects are hopeless. Instead, it extends size of my shell to width of biggest line.

I am trying to achieve that by creating class which extends shell

My constructor

```
    super(SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.NO_FOCUS | SWT.NO_SCROLL);
    FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
    layout.marginHeight = 1;
    layout.marginWidth = 1;
    setLayout(layout);

    mForm = new ManagedForm(this);
    FormToolkit toolkit = mForm.getToolkit();
    body = mForm.getForm().getBody();

    FillLayout layout2 = new FillLayout();
    layout2.spacing = 2;
    body.setLayout(layout2);

    body = toolkit.createComposite(body, SWT.BORDER );
```

And when I want insert and show text. I am do this like that

```
    String text = 
    body = mForm.getToolkit().createComposite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    GridLayout l = new GridLayout();
    l.marginHeight = 0;
    l.marginWidth = 1;

    body.setLayout(l);  

    StyledText bodyText = createDisabledText(body, text);

    mForm.getForm().getContent().pack(); 
    mForm.getForm().reflow(true);
    pack();

   setVisible(true);
```

and my create disabledText:

```
private StyledText createDisabledText(Composite parent, String value)
{
    StyledText t = new StyledText(parent, SWT.SHADOW_NONE);
    t.setText(value);
    t.setEditable(false);
    t.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    return t;
}
```

All is in class which extends shell.
What I am doing wrong or is there method like set maxSize?

Answer (score 0):

In your `createDisabledText` method, try passing `SWT.WRAP` style to the `StyledText` constructor.

```
StyledText t = new StyledText(parent, SWT.SHADOW_NONE | SWT.WRAP);
```